# How to get computed CSS of external URL?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, getcomputedstyle, external-url

Is it possible to get the computed style of different HTML tags from an external URL?

getComputedStyle helps me to get the computed style from my own web page, but I would like to extract CSS values of different elements from other web pages.

What I'm trying to find out is for example: font-size of H1 elements and color of H2 elements from a given URL like http://www.smashingmagazine.com/.

Is this possible? (maybe using a NodeJS express server and ajax?)
Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it's possible if you use PhantomJS.  PhantomJS acts like a browser without a display.  You can use it to inject scripts into a page that can send information about the web page back to your node server.